# winkey assigned as Multi key instead of Super

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys

I am running Xubuntu 18.04 and I have the following problem:

When I try to create a shortcut using <kbd>Win</kbd>, instead of **Super** I get **Multi Key** indication and I cannot create key combination (i.e. Super-T). For example I cannot use the following shortcuts that have Super in it:

[image: image of keyboard shortcuts]

This is my */etc/default/keyboard*:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,gr"
XKBVARIANT=","
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle,compose:lwin,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp_led:scroll"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

also the results of: `setxkbmap -query -v 10`

```
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,gr
variant:    ,
options:    grp:lalt_lshift_toggle,compose:lwin,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp_led:scroll
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete+ledscroll(group_lock)
symbols:    pc+us+gr:2+inet(evdev)+group(lalt_lshift_toggle)+compose(lwin)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,gr
variant:    ,
options:    grp:lalt_lshift_toggle,compose:lwin,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp_led:scroll
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question.
I run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and on the choice Compose key, I choose No compose key.

[image: screenshot]

I had previously chosen Left Logo key which had caused the **Super** been substituted by **Multi Key** when assigning shortcuts.